# Need wireless screen clonning and streaming media

Tags: streaming, tv, media

I have a LG TV which has USB input (play divx, xvid, mkv, everything) and I would like to connect it wirelessly to my notebook so I can play files directly from it's hd. I have found some solutions like the http://hsti.com/wirelessmediastick/overview Wireless Media Sticker, which I could plug in the USB port of the tv and stream wirelessly the videos from my notebook. But I would like also to be able to stream soccer videos which plays in different websites, so I would need to be able to stream the "screen" of the pc itself, something like intel widi (which my notebook is capable of also) or VNC. I'm looking to spend no more than 40-70 USD. So I came to the Roku players, but I don't know if they would be able to stream my notebook's screen so I can watch those soccer live games from the web. Unless there is some Roku app that can stream like widi. Suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this. http://www.iogear.com/product/GUWAVKIT3W6/ 
It will basically let you use your TV as an extra monitor, which will allow you to "stream" your videos to it.

Comment: They are expensive. Can the roku player stream like widi?

Comment: Not that I know of...

Comment: I'm thinking that intel widi is the way to go, since I can play anything via screen clonning wirelessly.

Comment: Does it just stream media (vids and pics) or screen share anything desktop / browser as well?

Comment: @megaSteve4 It allows you to use your TV as another monitor, so you can mirror your main monitor if you want.